# How to Conver Blob to Image (JPG Format)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, blob

i using croper.js for to crop and store a image. following function i use croped blob to convert image format. that function not working properly.

```
   cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toBlob(function (blob) {
        var formData = new FormData();

        var creimag = document.createElement('img');
        creimag.src = 'data:image/png;base64,'+ blob;
        var processeddata=document.body.appendChild(creimag); 

        formData.append('file', processeddata);
    });
```

Comment: *"How to Conver Blob to Image (JPG Format)"* ain't the proper question to your problem. The actual question here was/is *"How to append a Blob to FormData"*. You see this reflected in the answers. *gawicks* answers the question in the title, *sneeps* answer solves your actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are coding this, you are appending an `<img>` tag where a file/`Blob` is expected.

https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs#getcroppedcanvasoptions

This page has an example for this use case. You have to `append` `blob` to the form. Quote from the example code:

```
cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toBlob(function (blob) {
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('croppedImage', blob);
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try URL.[createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)

```
creimag.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```